# Can you generate a world with only one biome?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to generate a world that's one biome, because I wanted to search for lots of jungle temples if the world is just one biome, but I don't if there's a possibility. I'm not asking how I can change what type of biomes I want, that would be more than one biome. I want to find a way to make a world one biome. Is there truly a way to create a world like this?